# hide element if another is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `schedule.description` either has content or is null.

I am trying to hide the `h4` like I did for the `section_schedule_items` map div. But, I am having no luck after trying almost all conditional statements.

Is there a way to hide the `h4` title if the description is `null`? Even if the element is outside of the `section_schedule_items` map function?

Snippet:

```
{adv_event.schedule.map((schedule, index) => (
  <div className="col-md-12 med-spaces" key={index}>
    <div className="schedule">
      <h4>Event Schedule</h4>
      <div key={index}>
        {schedule.section_schedule_items.map((schedule) => (
          <div className={schedule.description !== null ? ( 'block' ) : ( 'hide' )}>
            <div className="schedule-item">
              <p className="item-title">{schedule.title}</p>
              <Markdown
                className="item-body"
                source={he.decode(`${schedule.description}`)}
                escapeHtml={false}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

What shows when there is content in the description:
[image]

When description is null (title still shows):
[image]

Looking to remove the title basically.

Comment: No, you can only access the specific description of a schedule within the map, but you could put the h4 within the map function

Comment: @Julian If I use it within the map function it shows up for each loop. Is it possible to create a conditional that shows the title for only the first loop? Or is that a completely different question?

Comment: `section_schedule_item` - an array, if one element of this array has a description and other not do you need to show `h4 `?

Comment: If all description are null or if only one description is null?

Comment: @EmileBergeron The graphql returns 'null' or a text description

Comment: You're not answering my question. You'd like to hide the title if all descriptions within the array are null, or if only one among them is null?

Comment: @brooksrelyt Do you think my answer fits? (see below)

Comment: I added images of what happens if it helps explain

Comment: @EmileBergeron 's question is of interest to me as well - one description null or all descriptions null?

Comment: Ok, you should first filter the array to remove the element which have a `null` description instead of rendering hidden elements. Then, you could just hide the title is `{filteredItems.length > 0 && (<h4>Event Schedule</h4>)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible way to identify if at least `one` of the descriptions is false with a condition like

```js
schedule.section_schedule_items.some(
  ({ description }) => !description,
) && ... // returns true -> so some are false
```

A possible way to identify if `all` of the descriptions are false with a condition like

```js
schedule.section_schedule_items.every(
  ({ description }) => !description,
) && ... // returns true -> so all are false
```

Comment: Use [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of filter when you want a boolean check. (or `.some`).

Comment: Also, the default param value (`= false`) is useless here since `undefined` is already falsy.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Appreciate the feedback, I have updated accordingly

Comment: `.every` returns a boolean, now your answer is incorrect in both example.

Comment: Then this should do it?

Comment: Now the title is hidden on the elements that contain description content not on the elements that return the null value. When the description is null the title still shows

Comment: @brooksrelyt Can you explain? What would you like to change?

Comment: Maybe I worded this poorly but, looks like it is working when I removed the `!` in `!description`  code: `{schedule.section_schedule_items.some(({ description }) => description,) && <h4>Event Schedule</h4> }`

Comment: Oh, I get it, sure! The `some` and `every` do return true, so it will show the title, you would have to negate the whole condition, which is the same as negating the condition in every or some

Comment: @brooksrelyt take some time to familiarize yourself with [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Notice how Julian is showing you both?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Absolutely, I will look into it. I was testing both. I really appreciate the help